# Populate cells with two numbers only using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me, what I am trying to do is to populate cells N2:N1041 with numbers 0 and 2. I want total of 100 cells (random cells to be filled in) in column N to be populated with "0" and the remaining 940 cells to have "2". Or in other words, I want the 9.6% of the range (N2:N1041) to be filled with "0" and the rest with "2".

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: have you had a chance to try the solution I suggested?

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a fairly simple exercise in controlling a `Do` loop.

First, set all the cell values to "2" inside this range.

Then, using the `RandBetween` function, choose random cells within that range to set to "0" value.  Add a check to make sure you're not overwriting 0 with 0, and then add a counter so you can control when to exit the loop.

```
Sub TestMacro()
Dim rng As Range
Dim count0 As Integer
Dim randCell As Range

Set rng = Range("A2:A1041")

rng.Value = "2" 'Set all cells = 2.'

Do

    Set randCell = rng.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 1040))
    'make sure we're not overwriting another 0-value'
    If Not randCell.Value = 0 Then
        randCell.Value = 0  
        'increment the counter variable'
        count0 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "0")
    End If
Loop While count0 < 100  'exit the loop once 100 cells have been changed to 0.'


End Sub
```